# How to fix locale settings in debian lenny (minimal)

Tags: debian-lenny, localization

I have  a debian machine running remotely, i tried many ways to fix this locale issue, which is harmless while using `apt-get` though but because of it my web apps are not functioning properly. I have quick googled for the solution and found that `dpkg-reconfigure locales` will fix the issues but I am still not getting it right.

```
idlecool@machine:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
[sudo] password for idlecool: 
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
Generation complete.
idlecool@machine:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try running `sudo locale-gen` to run `localedef` for the locales configured in `/etc/locales.gen`.

If this doesn't help, please post the `/etc/locale.gen` because than it would seem that he would try to set a locale not generated before.

Comment: i dont have any file `/etc/locales.gen`  even after issuing `sudo locale-gen`

Comment: hey! thanks! it helped.. please change `/etc/locales.gen` to `/etc/locale.gen`, it is the file. it uncommented my country character set and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm you might try to `aptitude reinstall locales`. Then select all languages you need and check with `locale`if it is set correctly.

Comment: even it doesnot help, i am getting the same errors